# How to see the expected result in this React Native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, wifi, native

I have an app, where it displays me the available Wi-Fi networks, I have to choose one, then writing a password to it, and in the process of connecting it checks for ping, DNS spoofing, location and connection time.

When I wrote the code, it only displays me the buttons of Available networks, ping, DNS spoofing, connection time and location, but when I click on them, nothing happens.
I turned off the Wi-Fi and Mobile data of the device, the code is written in this: https://snack.expo.dev/?platform=android
The code is:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';
import WifiManager from 'react-native-wifi-reborn';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-background-timer';

const backgroundImage = require('./cyber_security.jpg');

const App = () => {
  const [wifiList, setWifiList] = useState([]);
  const [selectedNetwork, setSelectedNetwork] = useState(null);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [pingResult, setPingResult] = useState(null);
  const [spoofingResult, setSpoofingResult] = useState(null);
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [connectionTime, setConnectionTime] = useState(null);

  // Fetch available Wi-Fi networks on component mount
 useEffect(() => {
  if (WifiManager !== null) {
    WifiManager.loadWifiList((wifiArray) => {
      setWifiList(wifiArray);
    });
  } else {
    console.error('WifiManager is null');
  }
}, []);

  // Fetch available Wi-Fi networks
  const fetchWifiList = async () => {
    try {
      const list = await WifiManager.loadWifiList();
      setWifiList(list);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error fetching Wi-Fi list:', error);
    }
  };

  // Connect to selected Wi-Fi network
  const connectToNetwork = async () => {
    try {
      await WifiManager.connectToProtectedSSID(selectedNetwork.SSID, password);
      console.log('Connected to network:', selectedNetwork.SSID);
      setPingResult(null);
      setSpoofingResult(null);
      setLocation(null);
      setConnectionTime(null);
      startNetworkInfoUpdates();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error connecting to network:', error);
    }
  };

  // Start updating network info in the background
  const startNetworkInfoUpdates = () => {
    BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(() => {
      checkPing();
      checkDNS();
      getLocation();
      getConnectionTime();
    }, 5000);
  };

  // Check ping connectivity
  const checkPing = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await NetInfo.fetch('isConnected');
      setPingResult(response.isConnected ? 'Connected' : 'Disconnected');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error checking ping:', error);
    }
  };

  // Check DNS spoofing
  const checkDNS = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await NetInfo.fetch('isConnectionExpensive');
      setSpoofingResult(response.isConnectionExpensive ? 'Spoofed' : 'Not spoofed');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error checking DNS spoofing:', error);
    }
  };

// Get current location
  const getLocation = async () => {
    try {
      // Fetch location using appropriate method based on platform (iOS/Android)
      // Replace this code with your actual implementation for getting location
      // This is just a placeholder for demonstration purposes
      const location = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('Unknown');
        }, 1000);
      });
      setLocation(location);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error getting location:', error);
    }
  };

  // Get connection time
  const getConnectionTime = async () => {
    try {
      // Fetch connection time using appropriate method based on platform (iOS/Android)
      // Replace this code with your actual implementation for getting connection time
      // This is just a placeholder for demonstration purposes
      const connectionTime = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('Unknown');
        }, 1000);
      });
      setConnectionTime(connectionTime);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error getting connection time:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ImageBackground source={backgroundImage} style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContainer}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>Wi-Fi Security Checker</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>Available Wi-Fi Networks:</Text>
          {wifiList.map((wifi, index) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={index}
              style={styles.networkItem}
              onPress={() => setSelectedNetwork(wifi)}>
              <Text style={styles.networkName}>{wifi.SSID}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.networkSignal}>{wifi.level} dBm</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
          {selectedNetwork && (
            <View style={styles.selectedNetworkContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.selectedNetworkText}>
                Selected Network: {selectedNetwork.SSID}
              </Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.passwordInput}
                placeholder="Enter Password"
                onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
                secureTextEntry
              />
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.connectButton}
                onPress={connectToNetwork}>
                <Text style={styles.connectButtonText}>Connect</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          )}
          <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.infoLabel}>Ping Result:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.infoText}>{pingResult}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.infoLabel}>DNS Spoofing:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.infoText}>{spoofingResult}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.infoLabel}>Location:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.infoText}>{location}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.infoLabel}>Connection Time:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.infoText}>{connectionTime}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  scrollContainer: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  header: {
    marginTop: 50,
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
  },
  content: {
    width: '80%',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 20,
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  networkItem: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
  },
  networkName: {
    flex: 1,
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  networkSignal: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  selectedNetworkContainer: {
    marginVertical: 20,
  },
  selectedNetworkText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  passwordInput: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  connectButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    borderRadius: 5,
    paddingVertical: 12,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  connectButtonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  infoContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderTopColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
    paddingTop: 10,
  },
  infoLabel: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  infoText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 14,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
});

export default App;
```

[text](https://stackoverflow.com)

This is the background image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRuMF.jpg)